# getAttribute in a php/Html file

Tags: php, html, getattribute

I have a PHP file, and I want to extract an attribute value with a `div` `id`.

Here the code:

```
<div id="vids" channelname="test">
<?php
 load_video(1,$channelname); //channelname mays contains "test"
 function load_video($start_index,$channelname)
 {
  ...
 }
 ?>
</div>
```

I would like to extract the value of `channelname` before the PHP function called (`load_video`) to use `$channelname`.

I tried this:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load('test.php'); //Same result with loadHtml() and load HtmlFile()
$element = $doc->getElementById('vids');
$attr = $doc->getAttribute('channelname');
```

But it doesn't work.

```
print_r($element); // No results
$element->getAttribute('channelname'); //Fatal error: Call to a member function getAttribute() on a non-object
```

Comment: I think you need to execute your php file by eval() then you can get generated html file by dom load. can you add full  cod eof test.php?

Comment: can you put output of print_r($element); in your question?

Comment: Try `$element->getAttribute('channelname');`

Comment: $element->getAttribute('channelname'); returns an error of the getAttribute() function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
ob_start();
include 'test.php';
$strResult = ob_get_clean();

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($strResult); //Same result with loadHtml() and load HtmlFile()
$element = $doc->getElementById('vids');
$attr = $element->getAttribute('channelname');
```

Comment: @user3185672 : i have tested it locally. It should work. can you try this and let me know if any errors?

Comment: It doesn't work for me :Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting! on line 4     ob_start();

Comment: Increase the value of xdebug.max_nesting_level in your php.ini

Comment: I think I understand the problem. The fact is the <div /> and the PHP function are in the same file (test.php). It works also if I creat a new file but I can't do what I want with that.